# Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller using dispatch_release

Tags: ios, objective-c, reachability

I am trying to use tonymillion reachabiity libaray however I am getting an error in part of the code that releases the items in the que.

This is what the error looks like **Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller**

this is what my code looks like

```
//create a serial queue
    self.reachabilitySerialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.tonymillion.reachability", NULL);        

    // set it as our reachability queue which will retain the queue
    if(SCNetworkReachabilitySetDispatchQueue(self.reachabilityRef, self.reachabilitySerialQueue))
    {
        dispatch_release(self.reachabilitySerialQueue); //error here
        // refcount should be ++ from the above function so this -- will mean its still 1
        return YES;
    }

    dispatch_release(self.reachabilitySerialQueue); // error here
    self.reachabilitySerialQueue = nil;
    return NO;
```

I am not sure how else to get around this and was hoping someone could provide some insight as my experiance with refrence counting is very thin.

any help would be appreicated.

Comment: `dispatch_release` is not needed under ARC. My copy of his Reachability class wraps those calls in an `#if def`.

Comment: Thanks going to go look at the new one.